# Is there an easy way to deal with files with long filenames and long directory names in linux?

Tags: linux, shell

Suppose I have a directory on my disk that has the name: `photos_with_my_friend_John_from_first_semester_of_my_graduation_year`

Now each time I want to enter this directory I must write the following command:

```
cd photos_with_my_friend_John_from_first_semester_of_my_graduation_year
```

I am new to linux and for me it is very boring to write this whole name each time I want to deal with this directory or any other directory or file that has such a long name. So is there an alternative easy way to do this?

Comment: Bash  tab ? It will expand the directory

Answer (score 2):

Most shells offer tab completion: You simply type `cd phot` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and it'll insert the rest for you (assuming the prefix is unique).

Comment: what about if the prefix is not unique ? like if there are more than one directory whose names start with "photos"?

Comment: @shady, that is why I suggest the use of symbolic links instead. See my answer below.

Comment: @shady Assuming you use bash, it'll use readline, which by default requires you to hit Tab twice if there's more than one match (and then it'll list all available alternatives and you can type more characters to disambiguate and Tab again). I don't like that, so I have `set show-all-if-ambiguous on` in my `.inputrc`; this makes it list potential matches after the first Tab (instead of waiting and seemingly doing nothing).

Answer (score 1):

How about using wildcards?  Say `photos*John*graduation` etc.?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a symbolic link for ease of access:

ln -s long_file_name short_file_name

then you can use short_file_name as you wish.